# Books by category published annually in Ireland

Tags: data-request, books, ireland

[UNESCO monitors both the number and type of books published per country per year.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_published_per_country_per_year)

It's very intriguing for me to notice that Ireland is missing from this list.

I was wondering how can I get such figures, at least a rough estimate, for any year for Ireland. Does anyone know a source for the numbers and categories of books published in Ireland?